# Deploy bokeh with jscallback in Flask(gcloud)

Tags: python-3.x, flask, callback, bokeh, gcloud

I am building a bokeh webapp, so far so good. Though I have reached a problem that I have no idea where to start to fix it.
 I have done a chart with a js_callback, locally it works just fine, once I try to deploy it though everything else deploys fine, except the plot with the js_callback.
Any help will much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

[data](https://github.com/Reinhold83/BokehFlaskGCloud_1/blob/master/BokehApp/Data/OverAll.csv)
[data1](https://github.com/Reinhold83/BokehFlaskGCloud_1/blob/master/BokehApp/Data/ageGroupYear.csv) 
[webapp so far](https://rnogueiracv.nw.r.appspot.com/bokeh)

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from bokeh.embed import components
from plots1 import houseStockPlot, vacantPlot, Transactions, NewRegistered, nonOccupiers, pie_chart
from tabs import maps, ageGroup, popOverall, naturalincrease, netMigration, mapDev
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap

@app.route('/bokeh')
def bokeh():
    script, div = components(houseStockPlot())
    script1, div1 = components(vacantPlot())
    script2, div2 = components(Transactions())
    script3, div3 = components(NewRegistered())
    script4, div4 = components(nonOccupiers())
    script5, div5 = components(pie_chart())
    script6, div6 = components(maps())
    script7, div7 = components(ageGroup())
    script8, div8 = components(popOverall())
    script9, div9 = components(naturalincrease())
    script10, div10 = components(netMigration())
    script11, div11 = components(mapDev())


    return render_template('bokeh.html', script=script, div=div, script1=script1,
    div1=div1, script2=script2, div2=div2, script3= script3, div3=div3, script4=script4, div4=div4,
    script5=script5, div5=div5, script6=script6, div6=div6, script7=script7, div7=div7, script8=script8, div8=div8,
    script9=script9, div9=div9, script10=script10, div10=div10, script11=script11, div11=div11)
```

.html file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.3.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-1.3.4.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-1.3.4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-tables-1.3.4.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.3.4.min.js" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/article.css') }}"  type="text/css" >
<link href="/static/styles1.css" rel="stylesheet">



{{ script|safe }}
{{ script1|safe }}
{{ script2|safe }}
{{ script3|safe }}
{{ script4|safe }}
{{ script5|safe }}
{{ script6|safe }}
{{ script7|safe }}
{{ script8|safe }}
{{ script9|safe }}
{{ script10|safe }}
{{ script11|safe }}

</p>
<center>
    <div class='bokeh'>
        {{ div8|safe }} 
    </div>
</center>
```

plot.py

```
def popOverall():

    df1 = pd.read_csv('BokehApp/Data/ageGroupYear.csv', delimiter=',')
    df1['color'] = viridis(len(df1.index))
    df1['2009.'] = df1['2009'].values

    source1 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(df1))


    p1 = figure(x_range=list(df1['Age Groups'].values), plot_height=300, plot_width=500,title='Irish Population Breakdown by Age Group',
                tools='pan, wheel_zoom, box_zoom, reset', toolbar_location='right')
    p1.vbar(x='Age Groups', top='2009.', width=0.5, source=source1, color='color')

    #plot style
    p1.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 45
    
    #p1.grid.grid_line_color=None
    p1.outline_line_color=None
    p1.axis.major_label_text_font_style = 'bold'
    #p1.toolbar.autohide = True
    p1.grid.grid_line_alpha = 0.6
    p1.grid.grid_line_dash = 'dotted'
    p1.grid.grid_line_dash_offset = 5
    p1.grid.grid_line_width = 2

    hoverp1 = HoverTool()
    hoverp1.tooltips=[('Group Population', '@2009')]
    p1.add_tools(hoverp1)


    tick_labels_p1 = {'100':'100K','200':'200K','300':'300K','400':'400K'}
    p1.yaxis.major_label_overrides = tick_labels_p1
    

    df = pd.read_csv('BokehApp/Data/OverAll.csv', delimiter=',', index_col='Year')
    df['color'] = viridis(len(df.index))


    xrange = (2009,2018)
    xrange
    yrange = (df['Population'].min(), df['Population'].max())

    source = ColumnDataSource(df)


    p = figure(plot_height=300, plot_width=400,title='Irish Population Growth by Year',
               y_range=Range1d(*yrange),tools='pan, wheel_zoom, box_zoom, reset', toolbar_location='above')

    p.vbar(x='Year', top='Population', source=source, width=0.5, color='color')
    
    #plot style
    #p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 45
    #p.grid.grid_line_color=None
    #p.x_range.start = 2009
    p.x_range.end = 2018.5
    p.grid.grid_line_alpha = 0.6
    p.y_range.start = 4500
    p.y_range.end = df['Population'].max()*1.003
    p.outline_line_color=None
    p.axis.major_label_text_font_style = 'bold'
    p.toolbar.autohide = True
    p.grid.grid_line_dash = 'dotted'
    p.grid.grid_line_dash_offset = 5
    p.grid.grid_line_width = 2
    p.toolbar.autohide=True
    #p.yaxis.axis_line_color = None

    hoverp = HoverTool()
    hoverp.tooltips=[('Year','@Year'),('Population', '@Population{int}')]
    p.add_tools(hoverp)


    tick_labels_p = {'4500':'450M','4550':'455M','4600':'460M','4650':'465M','4700':'470M','4750':'475M', '4800':'480M','4850':'485M'}
    p.yaxis.major_label_overrides = tick_labels_p


    select = Select(title="Year:", align='center', value='2009.', width=60, height=25, options=['2009','2010', '2011', '2012','2013','2014','2015','2016','2017','2018'])
    p1.title.text = 'Irish Population by Age Group ' +  str(select.value)

    callback = CustomJS(args={'source':source1, 'title':p1.title},code="""
            console.log(' changed selected option', cb_obj.value);

            var data = source.data;
            title.text = 'Irish Population by Age Group ' + cb_obj.value

            // allocate column
            data['2009.'] = data[cb_obj.value];



            // register the change 
            source.change.emit()""")

    select.callback = callback


    layout = row(p,select, p1, margin=5) 
    return layout
```

Comment: Are there any error messages in the browser JS console? You are specifying relatively ancient Bokeh 1.3.4 CDN resources, are you actually using version 1.3.4 of the Python Bokeh package in the Flask app? (The JS/Python versions have to match)

Comment: Hi @bigreddot Thanks for your reply, I have both bokes running with 1.3.4, so they are matching. The odd thing is that I do not get any eroor messages.

Comment: @bigreddot I will give a try following this page from bokeh docs https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html

Comment: It runs locally.

Comment: Messages in the browser JS console?

Comment: @bigreddot No, I get no message related to it. It runs locally as all the other plots, this one has a CustomJS callback. When I deployed the bit a have done, the plot isn't there. Could be the fact that my requirements.txt is missing a library or two. Which is intriguing cause it runs in a virtual environment. Could be the fact that I might don't have the right CDN for the CustomJS.

Comment: @bigreddot is there a specific CDN for Java Script callbacks?

Comment: @bigreddot Alright I believe that I have an idea what is going on. I need a script for widget in js. i loaded the page in my phone and the plot was there, though the title was changing following the widget, the plot doesn't update. While checking the CDN I noticed that it was missing. I will check it asap and let you know.

Comment: To answer your question, `CustomJS` is part of the main `bokeh.min.js` bundle, nothing additional is needed.

Comment: @bigreddot hi, I updated bokeh to the last version, readjusted the codes and it still doesnt show an error message, either shows the plot, now not even locally, it runs well in jupyter notebook. Is there an example of which CDNs you should add for Flask for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case something come across to a similar problem.
I updated bokeh to the latest version, readjusted all the deprecated models, I still didn't managed to deploy the plot with CustomJS, not even make it works locally(it was working before), anyhow I replaced my CDNs and it worked both locally and with gunicorn. Thanks @bigreddot for help.

```
<script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-tables-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```